# Change PDF in a PDF viewer dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, symfony, pdf

I got a PDF viewer in my HTML page, it's from a site named Cloud pdf.io whch gives me this code to get the viewer on the page :[Code for integrate PDF viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfHYM.png)

I got a function to get through my PDFs and get their token on the Cloud pdf.io website with JSON :

```
    $(".documents").on('change', function() {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   
                   var id = $(this).val();
                   console.log('Document séléctionné, ID : ' + id );
                   
                   $.ajax({url: '{{ path('docs_change_document') }}',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: { documentId: id },
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function(data){
                        alert("success");
                        console.log(data);
                        
                        },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);}
                  });
            });
```

```
But the PDF viewer wants me to write the following code to change the PDF :
```

```
    instance.loadDocument({
            documentId: 'a9658aef-c513-4130-afbf-77f3fc19e0e7'
        });
```

And i can't see how to modify these lines with my JSON.

Here is my page :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spSYu.png)

Thanks if anybody knows how to do that !